# Does iTerm (or iTerm2) on Mac allow storing host connections with user/password ( for quick access to different hosts)

Tags: macos, iterm

Does iTerm (or iTerm2) for Mac allow storing and quickly-connecting to hosts?

(for Windows, even PuTTY lets us save connections. not clear when it comes to Mac)

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no.

The usual way is to set an ssh entry as a profile in Iterm. Here is an example  for a local NAS.
[image: Example ssh profile]

The no is for the password - iTerm does not provide a way of associating the password with a login. But in practice this is not a problem as you should be using [Public Key Authentication](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication)

If you are not using PKA then look at use of expect with ssh e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786000/151019

Note saying "even Putty does this" is a very high bar, Putty is has a lot of functionality.

Comment: Comparing with PuTTY is also unfair because PuTTY is specifically designed as a remote login application, not just a terminal emulator.

Comment: Could the password be put into the "Send text at start" field?

Comment: Possibly - I don't know just try it - Note then your passwords will be unencrypted

Comment: True enough. It would need some kind of keychain integration to avoid that. But SSH's built-in PKA is the better solution, as you say. BTW, you misspelled it as "PSA".

Answer (score 3):

iTerm2 has a Password Manager window, which uses the system's keychain to securely store passwords. In my case it pops up a fingerprint prompt when you open it.
The password manager is separate from the profile (where you store your SSH command), but in the profile, "Session" tab, you can choose "Open password manager automatically" so it pops up whenever you activate the profile.